# navigate inside renderItem of Flatlist

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, react-native-navigation

I have a component `InventoryScreen`, which holds a `Flatlist` like this:

```js
 <FlatList
            numColumns={2}
            data={filteredData}
            keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
            renderItem={renderItem}
            stickyHeaderIndices={[0]}
            keyboardDismissMode={"on-drag"}>
</FlatList>
<TouchableOpacity
      onPress={() => navigation.navigate("ItemScreen") }> // <--- Here, it works.
</TouchableOpacity
```

Inside `InventoryScreen`, I can use `navigation`.

**renderItem:**

```js
const renderItem = ({ item }: { item: ItemResponse }) => {
  return <ItemView item={item} />;
};
```

**ItemView**

```js
const ItemView = ({ item }: { item: ItemResponse }) => {
  return (
<TouchableOpacity
      onPress={() => navigation.navigate("ItemScreen") }> // <--- This is what I want.
</TouchableOpacity
```

But, because there is no `navigation` available in `ItemView`, I cant navigate inside there. When trying to pass `navigation` to the `renderItem` gives me an error inside the `FlatList`:

`Property 'navigation' is missing in type 'ListRenderItemInfo<ItemResponse>' but required in type '{ item: ItemResponse; navigation: any; }'.`

How can I access navigation inside `ItemView` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this
**Root Component**

```
const RootComp = ({navigation})=>{

    const renderItem = ({ item }: { item: ItemResponse }) => {
      return <ItemView item={item} navigation={navigation} />;
    };

return (
<FlatList
            numColumns={2}
            data={filteredData}
            keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
            renderItem={renderItem}
            stickyHeaderIndices={[0]}
            keyboardDismissMode={"on-drag"}>
</FlatList>
)

}
```

**ItemView**

```
const ItemView = ({ item, navigation }: { item: ItemResponse }) => {
  return (
<TouchableOpacity
      onPress={() => navigation.navigate("ItemScreen") }> // <--- This is what I want.
</TouchableOpacity
```

Comment: Thanks ! Didn't expect the `rednerItem` to be inside the "root" component, thats what the other contributors expected, I think. It makes sense to do so.

Answer (score 0):

you can pass in the navigation props like a normal prop from the parent

```
const renderItem = ({ item }: { item: ItemResponse }) => {
  return <ItemView item={item}  nav={props.navigation} />;
};
```

hope this works

Comment: can't find variable `props`

Comment: look at your parent component, and locate the navigation object and send it as a prop

Comment: Thats my question, how can I pass it as a prop? At the level, where `FlatList` is, I **can** navigate. I updated the question with an example. As soon as I want to pass it to the renderItem, I get the error.

Answer (score 0):

Im hoping you have access to navigation here?  then just pass navigation as props

```
  const renderItem = ({ item }: { item: ItemResponse }) => {
      return <ItemView item={item} navigation={navigation} />;
    };
```

And use it like this :

```
const ItemView = ({ item ={}, navigation = {}}: { item: ItemResponse }) => {
  return (
<TouchableOpacity
      onPress={() => navigation.navigate("ItemScreen") }> // <--- This is what I want.
</TouchableOpacity
```

Comment: I have access at the level, where the `FlatList` is, but not inside `renderItem`.

Comment: Check my solution,  I've passed navigation as props in renderiten